# Gemcraft Labyrinth -- Obtain challenge medals in free version?

Tags: achievements, gemcraft-labyrinth

Several fields in Gemcraft Labyrinth have "Challenge Medals" listed; goals such as "Deal a total of 2,000,000 damage in one battle on field XY" or "Kill a total of 7,000 monsters in one battle on field AB". Is there any way to obtain these without buying the Premium upgrade to access the more advanced battle settings and such?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some challenges, like the 100 wave challenges and most of the challenges like the two you listed, are impossible without premium.